# Pandas grouping by heirarchical multiindex without losing other indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a heirarchical multi-index that looks like this:

```
In [1]: df
S                         A         A         B         B         C
foo                       1         2         3         4         5 
bar                      10        20        30        40        50 
2016-09-25          0.09321  0.101425  0.129751  0.129751  0.098990
2016-10-06          0.09321  0.101425  0.091678  0.091678  0.030795
2016-10-18          0.09321  0.101425  0.143422  0.143422  0.045204
2016-10-25          0.09321  0.101425  0.103444  0.103444  0.045911
```

Where `S`, `foo`, and `bar` are heirarchical indices, and the dates are the actual DataFrame index.

I'd like to group by `S`, and treat the hierarchical indices the same as the dataframe so that a `df.sum` or `df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum()` version would look like this, including the **foo** and **bar** rows:

```
S                         A         B         C
foo                       3         7         5
bar                      30        70        50
2016-09-25         0.194635  0.259502  0.098990
2016-10-06         0.194635  0.183356  0.030795
2016-10-18         0.194635  0.286844  0.045204
2016-10-25         0.194635  0.206887  0.045911
```

Comment: how would you expected the foo and bar to be after sum ?

Comment: Does `stack(0)` on the original dataframe and `groupby(level=0)` give you what you're looking for?

Comment: @Wen: Summed by group `S`? If they were treated as DataFrame data for the operation, then returned to the hierarchical index, that would be fine.

Comment: @Andrew: No it does not. There is no grouping (or summing or meaning) by `S` if I do. I still have 5 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this (note: you may not need the `.apply(pd.to_numeric)` if the dtype of level 1 and 2 of column index is already int).

```
dict1 = dict((i,'mean') for i in df.index)
dict1['foo'] = 'sum'
dict1['bar'] = 'sum'

df.T.reset_index().apply(pd.to_numeric)\
  .groupby('S').agg(dict1)\
  .set_index(['foo','bar'], append=True).T
```

Output:

```
S                 13        14        15
foo               49        53        28
bar              202       215       94 
2016-10-06  0.097318  0.091678  0.030795
2016-10-18  0.097318  0.143422  0.045204
2016-09-25  0.097318  0.129751  0.098990
2016-10-25  0.097318  0.103444  0.045911
```

---

New Data in Question:

```
dict1 = dict((i,'mean') for i in df.index)
dict1['foo'] = 'sum'
dict1['bar'] = 'sum'

print(df.T.reset_index(level=[1,2]).apply(pd.to_numeric)
        .groupby('S').agg(dict1)
        .set_index(['foo','bar'], append=True).T)
```

Output:

```
S                  A         B         C
foo                3         7         5
bar               30        70        50
2016-10-06  0.097318  0.091678  0.030795
2016-10-18  0.097318  0.143422  0.045204
2016-09-25  0.097318  0.129751  0.098990
2016-10-25  0.097318  0.103444  0.045911
```

Comment: Not quite... `S` isn't grouped. Can `foo` and `bar` be averaged also?

Comment: @mankoff can you simply your data and show exactly what you are expecting?  Make up some simple numbers and structure.  It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry it was unclear. I've put exactly the dataframe I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @mankoff what is the datatype of 'foo' and 'bar' strings or ints?

Comment: Wow. It works. It'll take me a while to understand that - it seems non-trivial, for what I thought was a fairly simple operation. Thank you!

Comment: @mankoff It took me a while to understand what you wanted.  Yeah, the trick is summing up those levels in the MultiIndex.  So, what I did is to remove them from the MultiIndex, aggregate them then move the back into to the index.  This is easily done with the dataframe transposed.   Glad, I could help.  Happy coding

Comment: I'll try to simplify this - I have the dataframe *before* I make the multi-index, perhaps I can do some of the work then. Thanks again.